# MySQL Database Server Is Utilizing More Than 85 % Of Memory

Tags: mysql, database, database-administration, mysql-5.6, mysqladministrator

MySQL database server is utilizing more than 85 % of memory eventhough there are only one or two connections running select statements

Memory utilization :

`[root@server1 ~]# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         80587      71466       9120          0        273        816
-/+ buffers/cache:      70376      10210
Swap:         5119       3873       1246`

### Top

`Tasks: 251 total,   1 running, 250 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 14.1%us,  2.2%sy,  0.0%ni, 83.7%id,  0.1%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  82521148k total, 73200520k used,  9320628k free,   280632k buffers
Swap:  5242872k total,  3966636k used,  1276236k free,   851116k cached`

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
15224 mysql     20   0  113g  67g 5480 S 95.7 85.5  14490:38 mysqld
 5053 root      20   0 4655m 132m 1756 S  0.7  0.2 238:44.07 java
 2400 root      20   0  942m 7084 1788 S  0.3  0.0  63:54.37 dad
    1 root      20   0 28052  552  332 S  0.0  0.0   0:10.99 init
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.27 kthreadd
    3 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:17.17 migration/0
    4 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   9:36.25 ksoftirqd/0
    5 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/0
    6 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:08.29 watchdog/0
    7 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:17.39 migration/1
    8 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/1
    9 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   6:27.07 ksoftirqd/1
   10 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:07.06 watchdog/1
   11 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:23.34 migration/2

Processlist :
------------
mysql> show full processlist ;
+---------+-----------+------------------+--------+---------+------+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id      | User      | Host             | db     | Command | Time | State        | Info                                                                                                                    |
+---------+-----------+------------------+--------+---------+------+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 3404546 | sampledb | 10.4.86.65:34777 | lordm  | Sleep   |  420 |              | NULL                                                                                                                    |
| 3411236 | root      | localhost        | NULL   | Query   |    0 | init         | show full processlist                                                                                                   |                                                                                                               |
| 3411356 | sampledb | 10.4.86.65:43134 | lordm  | Sleep   |    0 |              | NULL                                                                                                                    |
| 3411357 | sampledb | 10.4.86.65:43135 | lordm  | Sleep   |    0 |              | NULL                                                                                                                    |
| 3411358 | sampledb | 10.4.86.65:43136 | lordm  | Sleep   |    0 |              | NULL                                                                                                                    |
| 3411359 | sampledb | 10.4.86.65:43137 | lordm  | Query   |    0 | Sending data | SELECT

  'REJECT'
  , r.src_id
  , r.src_id
FROM sample_processd r
WHERE last_machine_processed = 0
GROUP BY r.src_id |
+---------+-----------+------------------+--------+---------+------+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

### Innodb buffer pool

```
mysql> show variables like '%innodb_buffer_pool%';
+-------------------------------------+----------------+
| Variable_name                       | Value          |
+-------------------------------------+----------------+
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown | ON             |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now         | OFF            |
| innodb_buffer_pool_filename         | ib_buffer_pool |
| innodb_buffer_pool_instances        | 47             |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort       | OFF            |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup  | ON             |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_now         | OFF            |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size             | 50465865728    |
+-------------------------------------+----------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Could someone please let me know the possible reasons for memory consumption in mysql and what are the fixes?

Comment: How much physical memory your machine has?

Comment: 78 GB is the total memory. Innodb buffer pool is around 48 GB

Comment: Nice question, but better suited for https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What is the total size of your DB? Could you check also what is the page faults regime for all processes? If very low, why would it be an issue for you how much memory is being used for buffering?

Comment: The number of connections is not related to memory usage.  What type of queries is it running?  Lots of unions, BI or data warehousing queries?